# Outline of two intersecting curves in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am trying to get the x and y coordinate an outline produces by two or three intersecting circles as shown in the figure. Coordinate of the two circles are available below.

How can we do this automatically using Matlab?

I have hundreds of figures like this.

What I want is just to get the x and y coordinate of the final shape.

[image]

```
   X          Y
 ================
 1.0000         0
 0.9848    0.1736
 0.9397    0.3420
 0.8660    0.5000
 0.7660    0.6428
 0.6428    0.7660
 0.5000    0.8660
 0.3420    0.9397
 0.1736    0.9848
 0.0000    1.0000
-0.1736    0.9848
-0.3420    0.9397
-0.5000    0.8660
-0.6428    0.7660
-0.7660    0.6428
-0.8660    0.5000
-0.9397    0.3420
-0.9848    0.1736
-1.0000    0.0000
-0.9848   -0.1736
-0.9397   -0.3420
-0.8660   -0.5000
-0.7660   -0.6428
-0.6428   -0.7660
-0.5000   -0.8660
-0.3420   -0.9397
-0.1736   -0.9848
-0.0000   -1.0000
 0.1736   -0.9848
 0.3420   -0.9397
 0.5000   -0.8660
 0.6428   -0.7660
 0.7660   -0.6428
 0.8660   -0.5000
 0.9397   -0.3420
 0.9848   -0.1736
 1.0000   -0.0000
```

The coordinate of the smaller circle:

```
   x          y
 ================
 1.4000         0
 1.3939    0.0695
 1.3759    0.1368
 1.3464    0.2000
 1.3064    0.2571
 1.2571    0.3064
 1.2000    0.3464
 1.1368    0.3759
 1.0695    0.3939
 1.0000    0.4000
 0.9305    0.3939
 0.8632    0.3759
 0.8000    0.3464
 0.7429    0.3064
 0.6936    0.2571
 0.6536    0.2000
 0.6241    0.1368
 0.6061    0.0695
 0.6000    0.0000
 0.6061   -0.0695
 0.6241   -0.1368
 0.6536   -0.2000
 0.6936   -0.2571
 0.7429   -0.3064
 0.8000   -0.3464
 0.8632   -0.3759
 0.9305   -0.3939
 1.0000   -0.4000
 1.0695   -0.3939
 1.1368   -0.3759
 1.2000   -0.3464
 1.2571   -0.3064
 1.3064   -0.2571
 1.3464   -0.2000
 1.3759   -0.1368
 1.3939   -0.0695
 1.4000   -0.0000
```

Comment: Why use points on the circumference instead of circle parameters (center, radius)?

Comment: Does the [`boundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) function give you the desired output?

Comment: @MBo because it may not be a circle.

Comment: @TroyHaskin thanks! I combine your suggestion with the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MATLAB R2017b or newer, use [the new `polyshape` type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.html). These have a [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.union.html) and [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html) methods (the question refers to "intersecting curves", but I have the feeling you are looking for the union of the two shapes). This would look like:

```
p1 = [
 1.0000         0
 0.9848    0.1736
 0.9397    0.3420
 0.8660    0.5000
 0.7660    0.6428
 % ... etc.
 ];
p2 = [
 1.4000         0
 1.3939    0.0695
 1.3759    0.1368
 1.3464    0.2000
 1.3064    0.2571
 % ... etc.
 ];
p1 = polyshape(p1);
p2 = polyshape(p2);
p3 = union(p1,p2);
```

You can plot your shapes using `plot`:

```
plot(p1)
hold on
plot(p2)
plot(p3)
axis equal
```

Comment: I also use the answer from @TroyHaskin